# How to send an e-mail with inheriting classes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, email

```
import time
class mesagerie(object):
    """mesage for e-mail"""
    def __init__(self, s="Error!"):
        global m
        localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )

        mesage = localtime, m.group(0)
        try:
            print mesage
        except(),e:
            print s
class email(mesagerie):
    """e-mail"""
    def pas5(self):
        expeditor = 'allex.alexa11@gmail.com'
        receiver = 'nita_alexa11@yahoo.ro'
        username = 'root'
        password = 'skgaming'

        try:
                ob1 = smtplib.SMTP('srv1.cutesouthchat.com:9267')
                ob1.starttls()
                ob1.login(username, password)
                ob1.sendmail(expeditor, receiver, mesage)
                print "Message has been sent"
        except(),e:
                print "Message has not been sent"
                print e


x=mesagerie()
y=email()
y.pas5()
```

I want to make in the first class a mesage and to send it in the second in a mail to a receiver.

I'm getting this error:

```
ob1.sendmail(expeditor, receiver, mesage)

NameError: global name 'mesage' is not defined
```

Class email isn't inheriting class mesagerie with all its attributes?

Comment: You need to assign/access the attributes through `self`. (You may also have other problems, but that's the first and most obvious issue.)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing functions/methods, attributes, and globals.

Each class has attributes, which **are** inhertied by subclases. If these attributes are functions, they are called `methods`.

However, the variable `message` is not an attribute of the class at all. It is an ordinary local variable in the `mesagerie` class constructor. **Local variables in one function cannot be referenced in another**, as you are trying to do. You need to assign `message` to an attribute.

Corrected code:

```
class mesagerie(object):
    """message for e-mail"""
    def __init__(self, s="Error!"):
        global m
        localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )

        message = self.message = localtime, m.group(0)
        try:
            print mesasge
        except(),e:
            print s
class email(mesagerie):
    """e-mail"""
    def pas5(self):
        expeditor = 'allex.alexa11@gmail.com'
        receiver = 'nita_alexa11@yahoo.ro'
        username = 'root'
        password = 'skgaming'
        try:
            ob1 = smtplib.SMTP('srv1.cutesouthchat.com:9267')
            ob1.starttls()
            ob1.login(username, password)
            ob1.sendmail(expeditor, receiver, self.message)
            print "Message has been sent"
    except(),e:
            print "Message has not been sent"
            print e
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! I know that i'm confusing them, i'm a beginner in python, i couldn't find anywhere something that can explain me good the classes parents and childs. If you know some place like this please tell me, it would be very appreciated.